# How to do referral concept in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, install-referrer

Hello I am android developer. I have  a question related to iOS. I want something when I ask user to install my application from iTunes once click on hyperlink that redirect to app which is on iTunes. I want to pass some referral code in that link (source from which user came to my app). Once app install then I want to get that referral code. How to do this in iOS.

This is doable in android like http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22561636-How-Google-Play-Install-Referrer-Works

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by Apple or the App Store. There is no corresponding way to do this.

Comment: Doesn't Google Analytics show traffic sources from which user came to your app ?

Comment: iTunes store doesn't give you anything like this.